# How to check for CTRL+s in Gtk3?

Tags: perl, gtk3

How can I check if a key is pressed together with a specific modifier in [Gtk3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk3) ? For example, here I want to check if <kbd>CTRL+s</kbd> is pressed:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 '-init';
use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new('toplevel');
$window->set_title('Hello world');
$window->set_position('center');
$window->set_default_size(500, 500);
$window->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub {
    Gtk3->main_quit();
});
$window->signal_connect('key-press-event' => sub { handle_key( @_ ) } );
$window->show_all();
Gtk3->main();

sub handle_key {
    my ( $widget, $event) = @_;

    my $key = Gtk3::Gdk::keyval_name( $event->keyval );
    if ( ($key eq 's') && control_pressed( $event ) ) {
        say "CTRL+S";
    }
    return FALSE; # FALSE -> means propagate key further
}
```

How should I defined the function `control_pressed()` above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$event->state` is of type `Gtk3::Gdk::ModifierType` which has [overloaded operators](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Glib.html#This_Is_Now_That).

> Flags have some additional magic abilities in the form of overloaded
>   operators:
>
> ```
> + or |   union of two flagsets ("add")
> -        difference of two flagsets ("sub", "remove")   
> * or &   intersection of two bitsets ("and")   
> / or ^   symmetric difference ("xor", you will rarely need this)
> >=       contains-operator ("is the left set a superset of the right set?")
> ==       equality
> ```
>
> In addition, flags in boolean context
>   indicate whether they are empty or not, which allows you to write
>   common operations naturally:
>
> ```
> $widget->set_events ($widget->get_events - "motion_notify_mask");  
> $widget->set_events ($widget->get_events - ["motion_notify_mask",
>                                           "button_press_mask"]);
>
> # shift pressed (both work, it's a matter of taste)   
> if ($event->state >= "shift-mask") { ...   
> if ($event->state * "shift-mask") { ...
>
> # either shift OR control pressed?   
> if ($event->state * ["shift-mask", "control-mask"]) { ...
>
> # both shift AND control pressed?
> if ($event->state >= ["shift-mask", "control-mask"]) { ...
> ```

Also, the constants for the [GdkModifierType enum](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkModifierType) becomes lower case strings in Perl. So the following should work:

```
sub control_pressed {
    my ( $event ) = @_;

    return $event->state & 'control-mask';
}
```